# Use Ubuntu in Window server 2008 in virtual machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, windows-server-2008

Recently our group has purchased Window Server 2008. Though most of us use Windows I require Linux system for my work.

I read about virtual machine but I am not sure which one to use to utilize complete functionality of Ubuntu in window server 2008.

I would highly appreciate if someone could suggest me the best suited virtual machine for my work. Since, I have no prior exposure in server I can't really do experiments unless I received some suggestion from the experienced users.

Many Thanks.

Comment: If you require Linux (directly), why not run it on your device? Does it have to provide some services? If so, which? Does anybody beside you consume those services?

Answer (score 0):

Either use vmware (evaluation) or oracle virtual box. You might get a slight better support (from community) with vmware.

- use bridged network interface to reach your network.

**disks**

- use 16 Gb for system disk.
- use local data disk if it fit.
- if not, do not mount SAN/NAS on Window, then present as disk, try to reach NAS/SAN directly from ubuntu.

It might not be possible to mount SAN from a VM, but if you need big amount of data on ubuntu, consider converting a physical host from windows to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of virtualization software: [Bare metal and paravirtual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor).  The choosing between these two major hypervisor types will depend VERY highly on your requirements and goals.

If you are planning on making heavy use of your Windows Server, you may want to do bare metal as will allow you to make full use of the resources of the host machine.  However, this requires a quite of bit of know-how of the virtualization software on top of the guest OS.

However, based on your question, my assumption is that virtualization is new to you and your group and you want to simply test it out.  If this is the case, using VirtualBox or another paravirtual hypervisor will be a good choice.

There is, admittedly, some debate as to whether a paravirtual hypervisor works as well as a bare metal but I personally do not notice a difference.  From a performance standpoint, you might squeeze more performance when doing a bare metal virtualization but unless you running high-performance software, you probably won't notice.

VirtualBox seems to be the popular choice for home users and some small businesses.  It supports a vast majority of major Linux distros and Windows.  Getting started is easy, especially if you're using the gui.  If you're going to install VirtualBox, I HIGHLY recommend [installing from Oracle's repository](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

There are a lot of resources online on getting started with VirtualBox.  The [official documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/) is a great place to start but lacks niceties like screenshots.